# Installing nodejs and npm on WDMyCloud server

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, debian, apt-get

I'd like to install nodejs and npm on my [WDMyCloud](http://www.amazon.co.uk/WD-Cloud-Personal-Storage-NAS/dp/B00FOKN7FG) server, but I'm having problems doing so. The server itself is running Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy).

I'm able to run `sudo apt-get install nodejs` without error, but upon running the command I'm presented with the following message:

```
nodejs: error while loading shared libraries: libcares.so.2: ELF load command alignment not page-aligned
```

And when trying to run `sudo apt-get install npm`, it doesn't successfully install:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: did someone prepare the nodejs package specifically for WDMyCloud ? you may need to recompile nodejs from source if that is possible on such a hardware.

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER I haven't been able to find anything regarding an exclusive nodejs package. There's barely anything online about doing this, only a few passing comments deep in forum threads.

Comment: sorry I won't be able to help as I don't have a WDMyCloud myself ; you will probably need to find a way to recompile node.js on your box or find the correct alignment compile time options to prepare your own package. maybe look at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3224

Comment: Can you show us your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WDMYCLOUD v4 firmware uses 64K pagesize (while v3 uses common 4k pagesize) to increase I/O speed. *All* softwares in the built-in Debian repository were built for 4k pagesize and are broken for use now. The error you saw exactly complained about that.

Refer to: https://community.wd.com/t/why-pagesize-64k-in-firmware-v4/94868

As workarounds, you can:

1. Build 64k softwares by your own (the ridiculous official suggestion)
2. Use some other people's reporsity (at your own risk). For me, I'm using https://community.wd.com/t/repository-with-software-worked-on-v4-firmware/94532. Its ffmpeg works well so far so good.
3. Downgrade the firmware to V3

Regarding Nodejs, I'm also a big fan of it but I didn't try out to build "it" by my own because it seems a lot of effort -- besides the nodejs and npm, we probably have to rebuild packages provided by npm. So I gave up on the cool idea of running nodejs on WDMYCLOUD.

If someone someday makes it, please let us know and we'd appreciate that!

Comment: The Gen 2 MyCloud uses v2 firmware (which is somehow *newer* than v4) and AFAIK you can't use v3 *or* v4 because it's a different CPU.  Anyway, WD does offer cross-tools, but the latest appears to be version 4.6.4, while node 4.0+ requires g++ version 4.8 or greater!

Comment: I was able to compile node using the latest cross-compile WD provided, and the binary actually runs.  But so far I have not had *any* luck installing npm.  The WD environment breaks assumption after assumption: for instance, "which" does not exist.  busybox "tar" doesn't support "--version" and this breaks detection.  Busybox appears to have a bug piping from a script.  Even if I manually untar, it can't find the js it tries to run, and if I manually run the script via npm-cli.js, it errors out with things like "setuid user id does not exist", presumably due to reliance on some cmd line util.